# Moving the mouse pointer using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I searched a lot about finding a way to make me move the desktop cursor using OpenCV but all I found is some demos for people who already did it.

what I know is that the function setMouseCallback gives me the coordinates of the mouse and more but i need to give the mouse some positions to move into it.

So can anybody tell me how can i do it using OpenCV C++ ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the mouse belongs to the user, and it's rude to move it, doing so is something that your OS handles. For example, in Windows there is an API function `SetCursorPos` - [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This has nothing to do with OpenCV.

Comment: I'll tell him that the program will move your mouse and i din't force him to use it , it's just a program that move the mouse cursor by moving your hand or when detect a certain object.

Comment: Ok, your choice, but it's still an operating system function, not anything to do with OpenCV. You didn't mention which OS, but you have an answer for Windows and it should be simple to find an equivalent for *your* OS.

Comment: i will try it , thanks sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this in OpenCV. OpenCV is a computer vision library focused around analysing and manipulating images and although it provides simple user interface (UI) elements do not get fooled into thinking it is a powerful user interaction tool.

Now, if you want to move the cursor in windows you can use `SetCursorPos` which I believe works on most versions:

```
SetCursorPos(X,Y)
```

e.g.

```
SetCursorPos(100, 200)
```